# Fixed-width space character with a variable-width font?

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to display a space with a monospace font, while displaying all other characters with a variable-width font?

I tried

```el
(set-fontset-font t '(#x20 . #x20) (font-spec :family "Source Code Pro"))
```

but the result was an error message saying

```
Can't set a font for partial ASCII range
```

Is this completely impossible, or am I doing the wrong thing?

Comment: It does seem to work for characters codepoints above ASCII range (0x80 and up), but that doesn't help you.

Comment: Have a look at `buffer-display-table`. This is used by `whitespace-mode` and its `whitespace-display-mappings` option (noting specifically the `space-mark` values for the latter), so to begin with you should just play with those. I suspect you can map a space to a codepoint which you can control?

Comment: @phils That's a really good idea, thanks! `buffer-display-table` lets me control the width of spaces, by mapping spaces to other Unicode spaces (like #x2007) that are not nearly as thin as my original variable-width spaces, and I can even change the font. Can you please post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Please feel free to edit your specific solution into either your question or my answer, so that others can see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `buffer-display-table`.

This is used by `whitespace-mode` and its `whitespace-display-mappings` option (noting specifically the `space-mark` values for the latter), so to begin with you should just play with those.

I suspect you can map a space to a codepoint which you can control?

*Edit (Kirill)*: This is a snippet that illustrates how this answers the question: it can be used to display spaces differently, which is what I wanted to do. It makes every space `#x20`, which is very narrow in some proportional width fonts, be displayed as a different kind of space, for example as one of `#x2000..#x200a`, which includes a choice of different space widths - https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html. It also seems that the font that the new space gets displayed with can be correctly set with `set-fontset-font`.

```
(let ((tab (make-display-table))
        ;; try #x2000 .. #x200a, plus there are some other Unicode space characters
        (cp #x2002))
    (aset tab ?  (vector (make-glyph-code cp)))
    (setq-local buffer-display-table tab)
    ;; Compare different fonts' space widths:
    (set-fontset-font t (cons cp cp) (font-spec :family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))
    ;; (set-fontset-font t (cons cp cp) (font-spec :family "Source Code Pro"))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that error message indicates that it isn't.

I suspect that you want this because in your opinion variable-width fonts look better, but you also want to use a monospace font for spaces because that would help reducing the effect on indentation.

That seems reasonable - and it might be a good idea to request this feature on [`emacs-devel`](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-devel).

Comment: Yes, the error message does seem to say that, but that's not really a definitive answer to this question. I already implemented something like this in propfont-mixed, but the question still stands.